# Check if a interface is implemented by a type in compile time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a project where I want to keep a reference to a `Type` and later initalize instance of that type. But I want some compile-time type-checking so I only can provide types that implements the `ITest` interface.  I think I have to change approach, but I can't see how.

```
private static Type currentType = null;

public static void Initalize (Type current){
     currentType = current;
}

public class Test : ITest{}
public class Test2 {}
```

It should be possible to pass in the `typeof(Test)` but not `typeof(Test2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why dont you use generics?

```
private static Type currentType = null;

public static void Initalize <T>() where T: ITest {
     currentType = typeof(T);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to change your `Initialize` method to:

```
public static void Initialize(ITest current)
```

Alternatively, you could use Generics to constrain the type e.g.

```
public static void Initialize<T>(T current) where T: ITest
```